# Why mysql matches NULL values with any string in WHERE condition?

Tags: mysql

I have simple MySQL tables (simplified for this question):

```
table A - id int, name varchar(255), id_b int
table B - id int, name varchar(255)
```

I have these values in table A:

```
1, 'a1', 10
2, 'a2', 11
3, 'a3', 12
```

I have these values in table B:

```
21, 'b1'
22, 'b2'
23, 'b3'
```

And I have this query:

```
SELECT A.name, (SELECT B.name FROM B WHERE B.id = A.id_b) AS name_ext FROM  A WHERE name_ext = 'something';
```

I am expecting to get empty result, but instead, I get all 3 rows from table A with value of `name_ext` beeing NULL. How is this possible ? And what should I do to get expected result ?

Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: This query should not even compile. I guess you simplified too much. You can't use an alias in a `where` clause

Comment: @juergend Then `A` must have a column called `name_ext`. But the OP shows a (simplified) definition of A. So it's probably a mistake in transcription for the question.

Comment: I am sorry, I made error when I was simplifying query. And then I found what the problem was in original query, but it is not related to this question, so I flagged it for deletion. Thanks everyone for your effort

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query is behaving correctly. It's equivalent to the following:

```
SELECT A.name, B.name 
FROM A
LEFT OUTER JOIN B ON B.id = A.id_b
WHERE A.name_ext = 'something'
```

If there's no match, then the outer join returns all columns in B.* as NULL. But the result of the query still has a row for each row of A.

Likewise in your version:

```
SELECT A.name, (SELECT B.name FROM B WHERE B.id = A.id_b) AS name_ext
FROM A WHERE name_ext = 'something';
```

The primary query returns a row for each row of A regardless. **If** the subquery finds a match in B, it returns that. Otherwise if it finds no match, the query still returns a row, and the absence of a match in B is shown by a NULL in the second column.

If you want the query to return *only* rows that have a match in B, use this:

```
SELECT A.name, B.name 
FROM A
INNER JOIN B ON B.id = A.id_b
WHERE A.name_ext = 'something'
```

Answer (score 0):

You will get an error message with your query. Because MySQL will understand that you are filter by name_ext columns in table A.

Anyway, you can use inner join query to get your expected result.

```
SELECT A.name as name, B.name as name_ext
FROM  A INNER JOIN B on A.id_b = B.id
WHERE B.name = 'something';
```

Hopefully, this is useful for you.